# Show records processed to user while fetching records from DB and writing to a text file

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to fetch records from my SQL DB and writing them to a text file when user clicks on the button. what I want is, no. of records is to be shown to the user during the process. like if there are 10000 records (say), so when user clicks on button, there should be a progress showing "No. of records written: 1,2,3.... " and so on. means user must be able to see that how many records have been actually written. here is my code, plz help to edit it to get the desired thing.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:Timer runat="server" ID="Timer1" Interval="1000" Enabled="false" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanell" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="Label1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="250px" width="800px"/>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Insert Records2" 
        onclick="Button2_Click" />
    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanell" runat="server">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            Update in Progress……..
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
</div>
</form>
```

and here is code behind:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = @"C:\Insert\Myfile.txt";
        string cs = "Data Source=machinename;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;";
        string sql = "SELECT ID from Employee";

        if (File.Exists(filename))
            File.Delete(filename);
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename))
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs);
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                StringBuilder myData = new StringBuilder();
                myData.Append(reader["ID"].ToString());
                writer.WriteLine(myData.ToString());
            }
            conn.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: display data from text file ,asp.net ? you could directly show from db know

Comment: sir, Progress I mean, our select query fetches records from database right?? So it must be selecting records one by one. lets say I have 1000 records, then my select query must be iterating through each record one by one right?? then what I want is, I want to show user on web page, one record processed, two records processed and so on.... so that user can see how much progress has been done.. and after processing I want to write each record in text file.. In in particular user will be able to see how much records has been written to text file and he will remain patient..